# How do I know which versions of .NET framework I have installed on macOS?

Tags: .net-core, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to determine the appropraite value of `TargetFramework` in my project on macOS. The current value, which does not work, is:

```
<TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
```

I can check my version of .NET using `$ dotnet --version`, but how do I known which versions of the .NET framework I have installed?

Comment: There is no version of the .NET Framework that can run on macOS.  You are using .NETCore.  Consider targeting it.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, the frameworks are quite new to me! How do I determine the correct string for .NETCore? `dotnet2`?

Comment: For .NET Core 2.0, you want `netcoreapp2.0`. Here is the official list of names to targetframework names: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#latest-target-framework-versions

Comment: You're probably trying to build for .net framework on macOS which isn't supported. Try using mono's msbuild instead and/or see https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/335

Comment: @omajid `netcoreapp2.0` worked. Please post as an answer so I can close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TargetFrameworks values supported by .NET ecosystem are described on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks.

For applications targetting .NET Core 2.0, you want `netcoreapp2.0`. For libraries, you might want something like `netstandard2.0` instead.